# Scala SBT CoffeeScripted, correctly override compile target

Tags: scala, sbt, target, absolute-path

Groping in the dark, I just resorted to a pathetic hack (note the path backtracking):

```
(resourceManaged in (Compile, CoffeeKeys.coffee)) <<= 
  (crossTarget in Compile)(_ / "../../../apache/static" / "js")
```

Is there any way to specify the *absolute target write path* with coffeescripted-sbt? The [intro/overview](https://github.com/softprops/coffeescripted-sbt) states

> You can override this behavior by overriding the resourceManaged
>   setting scoped to your configration and the CoffeeKeys.coffee task.
>   Below is an example you can append to your build definition which will
>   copy generated javascript to target/:scala-version/your_preference/js

That's great, but I'd like to write directly to apache statics directory, and not 4 levels deep in my sbt-eclipse project

Should note: I'm getting the *Unicorn is Angry* quite often on GitHub these days, so issue tracker isn't much help.

Thanks for any clues, what I have works, but I'd like to know how to set the absolute path properly

Comment: There's also an irc channel and a mailing list for SBT. The latter is really active, and the former, if you hang around long enough, is looked at by knowledgeable people.

Comment: Thanks @DanielC.Sobral, you're right, is really an SBT issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(resourceManaged in (Compile, CoffeeKeys.coffee)) <<= 
  (crossTarget in Compile)(_ / "pref" / "js")
```

Sets compile target relative to the default, which is "project_root/target/scala-version/"

The solution is refreshingly simple:

```
resourceManaged in (Compile, CoffeeKeys.coffee) :=
  file("/absolute/path/to/apache/static/js")
```

[SBT user group thread](http://groups.google.com/group/simple-build-tool/browse_thread/thread/b0d22d6efa1e3310)